# Objects of model does not have primary key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Unfortunately, I can't get out of a problem found in the code:
I created a new model to distinguish between sales orders and purchase orders.
The problem is that in no way is a primary key recognized when I create the object in question.
Through the admin section I create the object but if I try to click on it, it is not recognized, nor can I delete it.
Through Robo 3T I notice that compared to the orders of the first model, the second model has one less field, the one related to the id.
The models in question are virtually identical, but one works, the other doesn't.

***models.py***

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone


class Profile(models.Model):
    user_profile=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    btc=models.IntegerField(default=5)
    usd=models.IntegerField(default=100000)
    initial_balance=models.IntegerField()

class Order(models.Model):
    profile=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datetime=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    price=models.FloatField()
    quantity=models.FloatField()

class SellOrder(models.Model):
    buyer_profile=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    buyer_datetime=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    buyer_price=models.FloatField()
    buyer_quantity=models.FloatField()
```

***views.py***

```py
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Profile,Order, SellOrder
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from .forms import OrderForm, SellOrderForm
import requests


def home_page(request):
    price=get_price()
    return render(request,'app/home_page.html',{'price':price})

@csrf_exempt
def register_user(request):
    price=get_price()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username=form.cleaned_data['username']
            password=form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)
            login(request,user)
            messages.success(request,"Registration Successful!")
            profile=Profile()
            profile.user_profile=request.user
            profile.initial_balance=100000+(price*5)
            profile.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form=UserCreationForm()
    return render(request,'app/register_user.html',{'form':form,'price':price})


def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request, "You were logged out!")
    return redirect("home_page")

@csrf_exempt
def login_user(request):
    price=get_price()
    if request.method=="POST":
        username=request.POST['username']
        password=request.POST['password']
        user=authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('profile')
        else:
            messages.success(request,'There was an error logging in, try again...')
            return render(request,'app/login_user.html',{'price':price})
    else:
        return render(request,'app/login_user.html',{'price':price})

def personal_profile(request):
    price = get_price()
    profile=Profile.objects.get(user_profile=request.user)
    return render(request,'app/logged_in.html',{'username':profile.user_profile,'btc':profile.btc,'price':price,'usd':profile.usd})

def publish_order(request):
    price = get_price()
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order=form.save(commit=False)
            profile=Profile.objects.get(user_profile=request.user)
            if (profile.btc-order.quantity)>=0:
                profile.btc-=order.quantity
                order.profile = request.user
                order.save()
                profile.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Offer published!')
                return redirect('profile')
            else:
                messages.success(request, 'You dont have enough bitcoins!')
                return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form=OrderForm()
    return render(request,'app/new_order.html',{'form':form,'price':price})

def orders_list(request):
    price = get_price()
    orders=Order.objects.all()
    sellorders=SellOrder.objects.all()
    return render(request,'app/orders_list.html',{'orders':orders,'price':price,'sellorders':sellorders})

def order_details(request,pk):
    price = get_price()
    order=get_object_or_404(Order,pk=pk)
    return render(request,'app/order_details.html',{'order':order,'price':price})

def purchase(request,pk):
    price = get_price()
    buyer_profile=Profile.objects.get(user_profile=request.user)
    order=Order.objects.get(pk=pk)
    seller_profile=Profile.objects.get(user_profile=order.profile)
    if buyer_profile.usd >= order.price:
        buyer_profile.btc+=order.quantity
        buyer_profile.usd -= order.price
        seller_profile.usd+=order.price
        buyer_profile.save()
        seller_profile.save()
        order.delete()
    else:
        messages.success(request,'Ops! You dont have enough money...')
        return redirect('profile')
    return render(request,'app/purchase.html',{'quantity':order.quantity,'seller':seller_profile.user_profile,'price':price})

URL="https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD"

def get_price():
    try:
        response=requests.get(URL.format()).json()
        a=int(response['USD'])
        return a
    except:
        return False

def analytics(request):
    price=get_price()
    profile=Profile.objects.get(user_profile=request.user)
    initial_balance=profile.initial_balance
    actual_balance=profile.usd+(profile.btc*price)
    total_gain=actual_balance-initial_balance
    return render(request,'app/analytics.html',{'initial_balance':initial_balance,'actual_balance':actual_balance,'gain':total_gain,'price':price})

def publish_buy_order(request):
    price = get_price()
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=SellOrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order=form.save(commit=False)
            profile=Profile.objects.get(user_profile=request.user)
            if (profile.usd-order.price)>=0:
                profile.usd-=order.price
                order.buyer_profile = request.user
                order.save()
                profile.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Offer published!')
                return redirect('profile')
            else:
                messages.success(request, 'Ops. There is an error... Try again.')
                return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form=OrderForm()
    return render(request,'app/new_order.html',{'form':form,'price':price})

def sell(request,pk):
    price = get_price()
    seller_profile=Profile.objects.get(user_profile=request.user)
    order=SellOrder.objects.get(pk=pk)
    buyer_profile=Profile.objects.get(user_profile=order.buyer_profile)
    if seller_profile.btc >= order.quantity:
        seller_profile.btc-=order.quantity
        buyer_profile.btc+=order.quantity
        seller_profile.usd+=order.price
        buyer_profile.save()
        seller_profile.save()
        order.delete()
    else:
        messages.success(request,'Ops! You dont have enough BTC...')
        return redirect('profile')
    return render(request,'app/sell.html',{'quantity':order.quantity,'buyer':buyer_profile.user_profile,'price':price})

def buy_order_details(request,pk):
    price = get_price()
    order=get_object_or_404(SellOrder,pk=pk)
    return render(request,'app/buy_order_details.html',{'order':order,'price':price})
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but. During start of my Django project models creation I struggle a lot with migrations. As primary key are supposed to be instanciate automatically by Django, I suggest you to firstly check in your migrations if the fields['id'] is created.

Here an example of what it should look like:

```
migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Post',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)),
                ('content', models.TextField()),
            ],
        ),
```

If the field is missing you can rerun migrations and hope it's added or just write the missing line by yourself.

Comment: Where can i find this? Migrations what does it mean, which file.

Comment: @ClaudioFanzini. Migrations are files created when you export your models to create tables in your database. They are contains in directory called Migrations, to avoid any problem I advise you to remove all your migrations and then migrate again